# Elementary reason for no closed form for the sum of first n terms of harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, intuition

I tried a hard for getting a concise formula for the sum of first n terms of a harmonic progression.

After a couple of years, I found out that there exist formulae in the continuous case (say log n).

Is there any intuitive reason for closed formlessness of the sum for first n terms of a harmonic progression in discrete case?

Comment: No, there is not, because 
we do not know for a fact that there is no closed formula for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. Maybe there is, and it is yet to be discovered.

Comment: The fact is that closed forms are rather rare, both for sums and integrals.  Typical introductory courses lead to misleading impressions, because all you see are nice cases where closed forms do exist.  You don't really need a reason for a closed form **not** to exist, you need reasons when they **do** exist.

Comment: A simple application of [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm) (see [this book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html) page 73) shows that it is not a sum of a fixed number of hypergeometric functions. Maybe this sequence is done among the examples.

Comment: On the other hand, some might call $\psi(n+1)+\gamma$ (see [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)) a "closed form".  There really is no standard definition of "closed form".